# Cannot delete foorepo it still contains attached forks

Tags: rhodecode, kallithea

If I try to delete a repo in kallithea/rhodecode I get this message:

> Cannot delete  it still contains attached forks

I know that there is a fork of this project. The fork should survive, but the original should be deleted?

How to delete the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Go to the fork (example foorepo-new): Options/Settings/Advanced.

Set "fork of" to empty.

Now deleting of the original repo is possible.

Answer (score 0):

In RhodeCode Enterprise 3 we also added now option to detach, or delete forks when deleting origin repo.[image: Removing repo with a lot of forks]

This way you can decide what to do with a when you have a lot of forks